# POSTGRES: Appending where clause while using in a loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a function in Postgres that entails a loop like this:

```
  for r in (SELECT a, b FROM table_abc)
  LOOP
    return next r;
  END LOOP;
```

What I am trying to do to this is append a where clause. Something like this:

```
whereClause := 'blah blah'
....
for r in (execute 'SELECT a, b FROM table_abc' ||  whereClause)
  LOOP
    return next r;
  END LOOP;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that you could simply use `return query select ...`? Or even simply a `sql` function instead of a `plpgsql` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
    finalsql := 'SELECT a, b FROM table_abc' || whereClause;
    RAISE INFO 'Final sql is: % ', finalsql;

      for r in EXECUTE finalsql
      LOOP
        return next r;
      END LOOP;
```

I think the parentheses were causing some problem.